# RegExp.exec weird behavior on Firefox

Tags: javascript, regex, firefox

I'm trying to get the first image tag on a page. The regular expression below works on Chrome and Opera but not on Firefox.

```
var ex = /<img src=".+">/;
```

I only got the image tags which doesn't have the closing tags `/>` so this works.

This is the string that I'll use it on:

```
var str = 'dd<div><img src="http://img.png" alt="" align="none"></div><div>ddd</div>'
```

Executing returns null in Firefox:

```
ex.exec(str)
```

But in Chrome and Opera it returns an array. In which I just have to use `[0]` to get the image tag.

Any ideas? Seems like Firefox doesn't like my regex. 
I only need the first match that's why I'm not using the `g` option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do

```
var ex = /<img[^>]+>/;
```